# SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm trying to set up a Report server on my local machine, but I cannot get past the Database Setup step in the Reporting SErvices Configuration Manager.

I have SQL Server 2005 on my machine, which runs XP SP3.

I have reporting services installed, and the service is running, but anytime I try to setup the Reports and ReportServer database, I get the following message:

The feature "Using other editions of SQL Server for report data sources and/or the report server database" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the SQL Server Installation Tool.
Under Tools Select Installed SQL Server Features discovery report.

Tell us what this says.

Comment: I have 2005 Developer's Edition, with IIS 5, Reporting Services and the Database Engine.